# Can't solve non linear system

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to solve this system:

$\begin{cases}(1+y)(1+z) = 2\lambda x \\ (1+x)(1+z) = 2\lambda y \\ (1+x)(1+y)= 2\lambda z \\ x^2+y^2+z^2 - 1 = 0\end{cases}$

We can assume that $\lambda \neq 0$

How would you solve this? No matter in which direction I go it seems unpleasant.

Comment: This looks like it comes out of a maximization problem, using a Lagrange multiplier.  Is the idea to find the maximum of $(1 +x)(1 + y)(1 + z)$ over the unit sphere?

Comment: Yep, you got it! just wanted to avoid detail bloat and keep the question focused on where I am actually having issues.

Comment: I would guess you wanted $\lambda$ to be one of the unknowns to solve for, since that will give us four unknowns to satisfy four equations.  The equations are symmetric with respect to the roles of $x,y,z$ , so I would begin with the case where all three are equal.

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica shows eight possible solutions:  $(-1,0,0), \lambda = -1/2$ (and permutations of $x,y,z$); $(-2/3,-2/3,-1/3), \lambda = -1/6$ (and permutations); and $\pm (1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3}), \lambda = 1 \pm 2/\sqrt{3}$.  I can't see how to easily prove this, though.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Actually those are exactly the solutions, you get from my answer, once you do the last steps, which I didnt include.

Comment: It is borderline sadistic to put this in an exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some thought, hope they help.

Subtract the second from the first, you get 
$$(1+z)(y-x)=2\lambda (x-y)$$

thus 
$$x=y \ \ \text{or} \ \ z=-2\lambda-1$$ similarly, 
$$x=z \ \ \text{or} \ \ y=-2\lambda-1$$
$$z=y \ \ \text{or} \ \ x=-2\lambda-1$$

This means that either $x=y=z$ or

$$x=y=-2\lambda-1\ \ \text{and} \ \ z=2 \lambda$$

Well, you can study those two cases.

In the first case you get $x=y=z=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ in the second $\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
(1+x)(1+y)(1+z) &=&2\lambda x(1+x)\\
(1+x)(1+y)(1+z) &=&2\lambda y(1+y)\\
(1+x)(1+y)(1+z) &=&2\lambda z(1+z)\\
x^2+y^2+z^2&=&1
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Note in this case that if we switch as *unknowns* $x$, $y$ and $z$ with each other the system does not change. It is suggested that one of the solutions is $x=y=z$. Then $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x=y=z$ implies $3x^2=1$, $3y^2=1$, $3z^2=1$, that is, $x=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, $y=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $z=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Yes but there could be other solutions. and infact, there are other solutions as well.